# Passing Perl array to an Oracle prepare query for the IN clause

Tags: perl, oracle11g

I have exhausted all options trying to pass either an array,its ref and its joined string to the IN clause in Oracle 11.2. I mostly get "undocumented conversion" or "error possibly near <*>" indicator error with all tried cases.

What may be the optimal way to pass an array to the IN clause of a prepare statement in Oracle DB?

The prepared query is similar to :

```
$query = "select * from xyz join abc on xyz.t=abc.t where xyz.a IN ?";
$query_stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
$query_stmt->execute(ARRAY(0x11223344) ||(other tried option) 'string0,string1,...');
```

Error :

```
DBD::Oracle::st execute failed: ORA-01460: unimplemented or  unreasonable conversion requested (DBD ERROR: OCIStmtExecute) [for Statement "select
                distinct cast(vt.a as varchar2(30))
                    as a,
                trim(to_char(value)) as b
             from xyz vt
             join abc vtc on vt.c
             = vtc.c join w offer
                on vt.d = offer.d
                and vt.is_valid = 'Y'
             where vt.a IN (?)" with ParamValues: :p1=''6778168456141','6778179729141','6778200266141','6778203754141','6778208407141','6778224280141','6778224419141','6778236126141','6778249749141','6778256663141','6778260054141','6778276276141','6778285860141','6778317622141','6778321032141','6778341014141','6778347921141','6778365313141','6778370737141','6778404039141','6778405686141','6778424024141','6778443116141','6778481089141','6778529277141','6778538345141','6778591334141','6778595317141','6778619981141','6778692874141','6778767142141','6778778071141','6778797829141','6778816085141','6778867467141','6778883297141','6778895665141','6778978652141','6778996314141','6779024581141','6779081179141','6779119698141','6779125079141','6779128574141','6779128584141','6779128649141','6779128662141','6779128724141','6779142735141','6779146125141','6779146399141','6779152708141','6779153278141','6779163438141','6779164599141','6779168905141','6779187230141','6779210491141','6779278671141','6779288166141','6779304879141','6779328703141','67...']
```

Answer (score 5):

Unless the Oracle database driver provides some other way to do it that I don't know of, you need to use a separate placeholder for each element:

```
$query = sprintf 'select * from xyz join abc on xyz.t=abc.t where xyz.a in (%s)',
    join ',', ('?') x @array;
$query_stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
$query_stmt->execute(@array);
```

Comment: I will give this a try. Although, I tried something similar to this before, it didn't worked.

Comment: Now, they are being set as "undef" for all substituted values [:p997=undef, :p998=undef, :p999=undef]

Comment: I see you updated the question with the error you are getting but not your actual code (and that error isn't coming from code that uses my answer)